# PyQt Process sequence is not right

Tags: python, time, pyqt

I try to make a program and hope the process sequence is:

click apply button,
the apply button will change background to green;
button text change to 'clicked';
after 10 seconds, the apply button's background change to blue.

But right now, after I click apply button. the button text changed and background color skitpped green and changed to blue directly.

can I get help?

Attached code:

```
import time
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore
import sys

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example,self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.Display=QtGui.QLineEdit("Not click",self)
        self.Display.move(30,200)
        self.Button1=QtGui.QPushButton("Apply",self)
        self.Button1.move(30,100)
        self.Button1.clicked.connect(self.DoApply)

        self.setGeometry(300,300,300,300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Review")
        self.show()

    def DoApply(self):
        self.Button1.setStyleSheet("font:13pt; background-color: green")
        self.Display.setText("clicked")
        Dosomething()
        time.sleep(10)
        self.Button1.setStyleSheet("font:13pt; background-color: blue")

def main():
    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)        
    ex=Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()


import sys,time

def Dosomething():
    i=100
    for i in range(10):
        print i, '\n'
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: The sleep(10), is that just a place holder for a long-running function? In its place you actually are calling a function that takes several seconds to return?

Answer (score 0):

When a signal is sent, the slot it is connected to will normally be executed synchronously. This means it will temporarily block, and any events (such as painting widget backgrounds) won't get processed until it returns.

One way to avoid this situation is to use a [timer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtimer.html). This will allow pending events to be processed until the timer sends its [timeout signal](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtimer.html#timeout), and any slots connected to it are called.

**UPDATE**:

If you just want run a loop whilst keeping the ui responsive, just call `qApp.processEvents` periodically, like this:

```
    self.Button1.clicked.connect(self.DoApply)
    ...

    def DoApply(self):
        self.Display.setText("clicked")
        # stop user clicking again
        self.Button1.setDisabled(True)
        self.Button1.setStyleSheet("font:13pt; background-color: green")
        # do something...
        for i in range(100):
            # update gui
            QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
            print i
            time.sleep(0.05)
        # allow user to click again
        self.Button1.setDisabled(False)
        self.Button1.setStyleSheet("font:13pt; background-color: blue")
```

Comment: If I change the timer part with load a function. How can I do?import sys,time def Dosomething(): i=100 for i in range(10): print i, '\n' time.sleep(1)

Comment: Do you mean you want to call a function once every second?

Comment: Actually, I would like to call a function (I have a control function with python code. such as print), in the mean time, the apply button is green (let user knows that the program is running, don't click many times). thanks for your help.

Comment: @sunnylucky. I've updated my answer with a solution that should do what you want. Note that you _must_ call `processEvents` to keep the gui responsive while the loop is running.

Comment: @ekhumoro Instead of the loop with processEvents, would it not be easier to use QTimer again to call another method that changes style again? If so it would also make intent clearer.

Comment: @Schollii. No, because that could block between the two timer events, which would take you back to the problem the OP started with. However, I've just realized the timer is now redundant in my updated example, so I've simplified things a little bit (basically, all that's needed is to periodically call `processEvents` in the `Dosomething` function).

Comment: @ekhumoro Easier to show with code, I created separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The GUI can only respond to user events in between calls to event handlers. So if you have a function that takes a long time to return, the GUI can't respond while the function is running, so it can't refresh, etc, it will appear to freeze. Easiest is to run the function in a separate thread and use Qt's signals to indicate task done, thereby updating the button state (not tested):

```
class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    class DoSomething(QtCore.QThread)
         ...
        def run(self):
            ... do stuff that takes a long time ...

    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.doSomething = None

    def initUI(self):
        ...
        self.Button1.clicked.connect(self.DoApply)
        ...

    def DoApply(self):
        self.Button1.setStyleSheet("font:13pt; background-color: green")
        self.Display.setText("clicked")

        -- time.sleep(10) -- will freeze GUI so perform in separate thread:
        self.doSomething = self.DoSomething()
        def onDone():
            self.doSomething = None
            self.Button1.setStyleSheet("font:13pt; background-color: blue")
        self.doSomething.finished.connect(onDone)
        self.doSomething.start()
```

Comment: Did you actually test your code? The OP wants the button to change to green, then call `Dosomething` (which takes a few seconds to complete), and then change to blue. I'm assuming the program isn't actually supposed to sleep for ten seconds _as well_ - that's just been left in there by mistake (see the [original example code](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/22747389/1)). I should also point out that your suggestion is quite similar to my [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/22748034/1) :)

Comment: @ekhumoro I got here late so I didn't see your first but I checked your link and you're 100% correct my answer is basically same, if I can't come up with something else I will delete.

Comment: I don't mind at all - I just thought it was a bit amusing that the answers came out so similar (it would have been even funnier if your answer got accepted :). Anyhow, it looks like the [OP is done with this question now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747389/pyqt-process-sequence-is-not-right/22775657?noredirect=1#comment34748740_22748034), so I suppose we may never know what they were actually trying to achieve...

Comment: @ekhumoro LOL it would have been funny indeed. I've updated to use a thread instead of what I had, not tested but OP should get the idea. This is sufficiently different approach from yours, who knows, might be worthwhile, maybe OP will revisit eventually. Cheers!